# Android (Kotlin): Type mismatch in Observer

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am implementing an MVVM Android architecture in which in the main application component (`MainActivity`), I listen to the `ModelView`'s `LiveData` storage for any changes. However, in the following piece of code:

```
private final var viewModel:ScheduleViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ScheduleViewModel::class.java)

viewModel.getSchedule().observe(this, object:Observer<String> {
    fun onChanged(feed:String){
    }
})
```

I get the following error:

```
Required: Observer<in String!>
Found:
```

Below are my imports:

```
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Base64
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager
import androidx.loader.content.Loader
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.example.mvvmarchitecture.ui.main.TabsAdapter
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import java.io.InputStream
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import java.util.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `viewModel.getSchedule()` return?
if your function is defined like this

```
fun getSchedule():MutableLiveData<String>(){
// your code
return liveDataOfString
}
```

this it should compile.

```
viewModel.getSchedule().observe(this, object :androidx.lifecycle.Observer<in String> {
            override fun onChanged(t: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

To fix that, replace `Observer<String>` with `Observer<in String>`.

But even easier, use a lambda instead of an anonymous object, so you don't have to worry about matching up the type:

```
viewModel.getSchedule().observe(this) { feed ->
    //...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the following error: Required: Observer<in String!>, Found: (Nothing) -> Unit

Comment: Can you add your imports to the question?

Comment: Added the imports :D